# Seasonality by day of month

Tags: r, time-series

I want to check for seasonality in a time series by the day of the month.
The problem is that the months are not of equal length (or frequency) - there are months with 31, 28 & 30 days.
When declaring the `ts` object I can only specify a fixed frequency so it wont be correct.

```
> x <- data.frame(d = as.Date("2013-01-01") + 1:365 , v = runif(365))
> tapply(as.numeric(format(x$d,"%d")) , format(x$d,"%m") , max)
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 
31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31
```

How can I create a time series object in r that i can later decompose and check for seasonality ?

Is it possible to create a pivot table and convert it into a ts ?

Comment: You should not use months when defining seasonality. The Earth's rotation is regular, the months are irregular.

Comment: I had a similar problem and solved it by first making the lengths of months equal, e.g. 30 days in your case. Is that justifiable in your problem?

Comment: @DWin - but what if your data *is* seasonal on a monthly base ? (think of a gym where all subscribers are renewing / canceling their subscriptions on the beginning and end of the month).

Comment: @Julius - so you added the last day of the month to the 30'th - didn't you get a peak even though there wasn't one ?

Comment: Sorry, now I realise that I was a bit unclear. I had months with 21-28 days and then extrapolated, interpolated them using splines to make them all of length 26 or so. For example `spline(y = rnorm(18), x = 1:18, n = 21)$y` from 18 days to 21.

Comment: You should say what you want to do. There are methods for working with irregular time series, even a package named 'its', but also packages 'zoo' and 'xts'.